# How can I emit a fabric.js event from the outside

Tags: html, canvas, three.js, fabricjs

How can I emit a fabric.js event from the outside.
Let's say I have a 3D model that, going back to the position of the mouse, gives me the uv coordinates of the canvas ... I would like to emit click, mousemove, mouseup events
At the moment everything is perfect if I try to emit a simple click event and then select an element within the fabric.js canvas .. but if I try to move it (therefore through the mousemove event) the values ​​of the canvas uv ratio get misaligned

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to trigger a mousedown event on your FabricJS canvas programmatically. The "mousedown" event type can be substituted for whatever event type you need ('mouseup', 'mousemove', etc.)

```
var evt = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
  clientX: 400,
  clientY: 300
});
canvas.upperCanvasEl.dispatchEvent(evt);
```